# Azure Elastic Scale: Split-Merge Tutorial - Can't Split a Shard

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

I followed the tutorial [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-configure-deploy-split-and-merge/#testing-your-split-merge-service-deployment) I created all the things mentioned and deployed the service. I can run it properly as well.

My Elastic DB currently contains ONE range shard with `MinValue` set to `0`, and `MaxValue` set to `Infinity (NULL)`.

Then to actually split this shard into TWO. I did following:

1. Created a new DB with same schema as shard 1
2. Ran the service and it said the target db has to be part of the shard mappings. FAILED !!!
3. Now to add the new DB as a shard in the `Shard Map Manager Database`, I downloaded .Net API available at Nuget [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Service.SplitMerge), modified the settings etc, but it wont add a new shard as the first shard range (0 - INFINITY) wont allow it. FAILED AGAIN :(
4. Now I got my hands dirty and modified the actual `[__ShardManagement].[ShardMappingsGlobal]` table itself which contain these range mappings in `Shard Map Manager Database`. I went there and set the MaxValue column for the only shard to, say, 20. While this shard contains, say, sharding key upto 30.
5. Now again ran the downloaded .Net API, specifying the new shard start value to 20 - INFINITY.  It worked and new shard was registered in SMM DB.

(I thought that the service would now split shard 1, get all data with sharding key 21, and would insert into shard TWO as its MinValue is 21.)

6. Ran the service again, and it threw the following error:

   *The source and target mappings both point to the same shard 'new_shard'.*

hmmm... may be this is because the `MaxValue` of first shard and `MinValue` of new shard are same.

7. Now i went and updated the `MaxValue = NULL (INFINITY)` for the first shard which I want to split. Ran the service again, and recieved the following error:

   *The source and target mappings both point to the same shard 'new_shard'.*

What the hell is going on? Why is this so hard? Where is proper documentation for this?

This is very important to me, and I would appreciate any help in splitting the damn shard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your question on split/merge. Let's see whether this helps:

Based on the steps you documented above, it seems that you ended up doing two things in Step 3):

- you added a new database as an empty shard to your shard map, and
- you tried to assign a mapping that points to the newly added shard.

The first part (adding the empty shard) should have succeeded, while the second part (adding a mapping) would have failed in your case because of the existing mapping to the first shard which already covers the complete domain.

If this sounds about right so far, can you try the following steps:

1. Reset your shard map to the original state so that the (0 - Infinity)
   range points again to the first shard. It might be best just to recreate the shard map from scratch.
2. Rerun your Step 1) above 
   to have a clean database with your schema.
3. Add the clean database from the previous step as a shard to your existing shard map with a call like this: shardmap.CreateShard(new ShardLocation(shardServer, "your_clean_database"));. Make sure that you do NOT call shardmap.CreateRangeMapping(.). It is not needed and it will fail again because the (0 - Infinity) range is assigned to your first shard. The split operation will change your mappings as part of its operation.
4. Submit the split operation.

In any case, please do not modify the [__ShardManagement] tables directly. They are maintained through the APIs of the library you pulled from Nuget or the Split/Merge tool.

Here are a few pointers to additional documentation:

- Split/Merge overview: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-overview-split-and-merge/
- Shard map management APIs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-add-a-shard/

Hope this helps. If you are still running into issues, please reach out to me offline at torsteng(at)microsoft(dot)com.

Thanks,
Torsten

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and links. And sorry for my late reply, I was away due to Eid holidays. I will do that and will inform you. thanks again

Comment: A quick update: We have published ShardManagement powershell module along with some sample scripts here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-DB-Elastic-731883db. This should help you in settings and querying the existing range/list mappings.